# Is it possible to have a wildcard CNAME Record and an MX Record?

Tags: dns, cname, mx-record

Is it possible to have a wildcard CNAME Record and an MX Record? Would these conflict?

```
 *.example.com CNAME example.com
   example.com   MX 1 aspmx.l.google.com
```

Answer (score 1):

They won't conflict since they are not on the same name (`*.example.com` vs `example.com`), once you put things in proper zonefile format.

But you could even simply say:

```
*.example.com   MX 1 aspmx.l.google.com
```

Of course this is only half of the story, as the host under the `MX` record must also be properly configured to receive emails coming from all subdomains.

You can easily check things like that using `named-checkzone`.

```
$ cat zone1
example.com.    1   IN SOA ns.icann.org. noc.dns.icann.org. (
                2019112601 ; serial
                7200       ; refresh (2 hours)
                3600       ; retry (1 hour)
                1209600    ; expire (2 weeks)
                3600       ; minimum (1 hour)
                )

example.com.    1   IN NS   a.iana-servers.net.
example.com.    1   IN NS   b.iana-servers.net.

*.example.com 1 CNAME example.com
example.com   1 MX 1 aspmx.l.google.com


$ named-checkzone -i none example.com zone1
zone example.com/IN: loaded serial 2019112601
OK
```